# bind_param is causing an error, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: php, mysqli

This is a project for school. I'm am trying to post to the database, but after I click on submit it comes back with an error about the line with bind_param:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in /var/www/html/ticketsysteem/acties/nieuwTicket.php:42 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/ticketsysteem/acties/nieuwTicket.php on line 42

Can somebody help me?

```html
<?php
//var
$naam = trim($_POST["klantNaam"]);
$achternaam = trim($_POST["klantAchternaam"]);  
$tel = trim($_POST["klantTel"]); 
$adres = trim($_POST["klantAdres"]); 
$postcode = trim($_POST["klantPostc"]); 
$stad = trim($_POST["klantStad"]); 
$email = trim($_POST["klantEmail"]);

//nieuwe klant
if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
        $insertklant= $connectie->prepare("INSERT INTO klant klantAchternaam = $achternaam,
                klantNaam = $naam, klantTel = $tel, klantAdres = $adres, klantPostc = $postcode,
                klantStad = $stad, klantEmail = $email");      
  $insertklant->bind_param('sssssss', $achternaam, $naam, $tel, $adres, $postcode, $stad, $email);

  if($insertklant->execute()) {
   echo 'gelukt!';
  }
}
?>  
            <form name="nieuwTicket" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
                <button onclick="nieuwek()" type="button" id="nk" >nieuwe klant </button>
                    <label class="hidden01">naam:</label><input id="text1" type="text" name="klantNaam" class="hidden"/><br>
                    <label class="hidden01">achternaam:</label><input id="text1" type="text" name="klantAchternaam" class="hidden"/><br>
                    <label class="hidden01">adres:</label><input id="text1" type="text" name="klantAdres" class="hidden"/><br>
                    <label class="hidden01">postcode:</label><input id="text1" type="text" name="klantPostc" class="hidden"/><br>   
                    <label class="hidden01">woonplaats:</label><input id="text1" type="text" name="klantStad" class="hidden"/><br>
                    <label class="hidden01">telefoonnummer:</label><input id="text1" type="text" name="klantTel" class="hidden"/><br>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="invoeren" class="hidden">
            </form>
```

Comment: `klantEmail = $email");` is open to sql injection. secondly, if `prepare` returns `false`..... well, it aint a object right? I don't get it, why use prepare at all?

Comment: i was trying something new, just saw it on yt and thought might give it a try but i dont have to use prepare?

Comment: No, preparing is *good*. You're using it completely wrong.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue with the given answer?

Answer (score 2):

Learn how to use prepared statements and what they actually do:

```
<?php    

  $stmt = $connectie->prepare("
    INSERT INTO klant
      klantAchternaam = ?,
      klantNaam = ?,
      klantTel = ?,
      klantAdres = ?,
      klantPostc = ?,
      klantStad = ?,
      klantEmail = ?
  ");

  if($stmt){
    $stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $achternaam, $naam, $tel, $adres, $postcode, $stad, $email);

    if($stmt->execute()) {
      echo 'gelukt!';
    }
  }

?>
```

Your current code is wide open to sql injection, while the above code is fully secured against them. The whole idea of prepared statements is that you *never* have to concat *user submitted values* ***directly*** to the sql query.